# Adding numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How can I add a small numpy array to a part of big numpy array?
My code is like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((10, 15))
```

I want to add a 3 by 3 np array to the middle or some location that I can designate.

Comment: Look into [`slicing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by adding you mean assigning values from `3x3` matrix into your `x` matrix, then you can assign it to the slice of your `x` matrix. Example -

```
x[row:row+3,col:col+3] = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) #Your 3x3 array on right side.
```

Demo -

```
In [98]: x = np.ones((10,15))

In [99]: x[3:6,3:6] = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [100]: x
Out[100]:
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.]])
```

---

If by add, you meant to add the values up at the corresponding indexes, you can use `+=` in the above slicing assignment. Example -

```
x[row:row+3,col:col+3] += np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) #Your 3x3 array on right side.
```